# How can I specify a specific TFS folder in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

I'm trying to add a Team Foundation Server address to Visual Studio 2008.  However, the modal won't let me specify a directory to use after the port-number.

In other words, I'd like to specify http://www.example.com:8080/tfs .  However, using the following modal (pictured below), I'm only able to specify http://www.example.com/tfs:8080 (which isn't valid).

If it matters, I'm running VS2008 in Windows 7, attempting to connect to TFS 2010.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long time since I used VS2008, but you should be able to either type the full URL in, including the protocol, or leave off everything but the server name.

So, `http://examplecom:8080/tfs` or `example.com`

Also, make sure you've installed the VS 2008 forward compatibility hotfox: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/chrad/2010/01/08/visual-studio-2008-connecting-to-tfs-2010-server/